# svn hooks can't active for linux

Tags: linux, svn, hook

Code in post-commot.tmpl

```
REPOS="$1"
REV="$2"
export LANG=zh_CN.UTF-8
midir a
```

I wanna sync code to web server by svn,testing the code i find svn hooks can't active,I Hope to get help,thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Post-commit hook must

   - be named `post-commit.sh`
   - have correct shebang-string
   - have executable bit ON
   - use at least m**k**dir command

Comment: I have renamed post-commit.tmpl as post-commit.sh.The two files can be run.but when svn commit the svn hooks  Can't execute.Could it be SVN account access problems?

Comment: have saved,file name should  name post-commit,isn't post-commit.sh,thanks